# Getting a last name range using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need to pull back all of the accounts in a customers database which have a given last name range.  Examples would be AAA-FAA which should cover all the records before FAA such as EZZ,EYY,EXX,etc, etc.  Right now what I have obviously doesn't work.  I've got

```
where name REGEXP '^[A-F][A-A][A-A]$'
```

Any thoughts how to do this with MySQL easily?  Regex seems like the best option but can't get my head around it.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would this not just be a `>` and `<` filter with an appropriate alphabetic collation on the column? I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: can you do `where name >= 'AAA' and name <= 'FAA'` and it would just do the right thing....

Comment: @MikeBrant your answer is basically the most accurate but I can't award it without it being an "answer".  Would love to send you some love for making me stop overthinking.

Comment: I didn't write an answer, because soon after I commented, I saw @GordonLinoff post an answer which same suggestion. I would have just been adding a duplicate answer. You should accept his answer if you have decided to take this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, you could just use inequality comparisons:

```
where name >= 'A' and name < 'F'
```

The next range would be something like:

```
where name >= 'F' and name < 'K'
```

And, a nice bonus to this is that the expression can make use of an index, if one is available.  However, this presumably fetches a lot of data, so a non-clustered index might not be a big help here.

Comment: It should match BAC, which it appears this wouldn't really do?  I need to match 2, 3, maybe 4 or more of the letters the last name starts with.  not just the first letter

Comment: @kinabalu . . . Of course the first query would match "BAC".   That is greater than "A" and less than "F".  Think about where it would be in a dictionary.

Comment: @kinabalu - If BAC should not be matched, then edit your Question to explain why.

Comment: @kinabalu . . . Your comment seems at odds with the question being asked.  If you have a different question, please ask it as a separate question.  Include relevant sample data and desired results, so it is as clear as possible.